# do, while loops. Cannot output the contents of the loop

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop, counter

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to run a program in C#. What I need is for the user to enter their current bank balance, the amount they require to have and the interest rate. I want the output to show their balance each year and how many years it would take to reach their required amount. Thanks for your help. Below is the code that I already have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Interest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int time = 1;//1 means 1 year
            int count = 0;
            int num = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter current balance:");
        double Bal = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter required balance:");
        double required = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter interest rate: %");
        double IR = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        double TotalAmount = Bal * IR / 100 * time + Bal;//math to work out interest gained

        Console.WriteLine("Your balance at the end of year 1 is {0:C}", TotalAmount);//this shows the interest gained over 1 year

        //do
        //{
           // Console.WriteLine(Bal);
           // Bal++;
       // } while (Bal < required);

        //I need the code to keep looping until the bal is the same as required
        do {
            TotalAmount =+ count;
        count++;

        } while(TotalAmount < required);
        Console.WriteLine("It took {0} years to get to {1:C}",count, required);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is _not working_ exactly? Your question is little bit unclear.

Comment: Shouldnt that be += ?

Comment: I'm flagging to close this because it looks like a simple typo of the `+=` operator here. `=+` => `+=`

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment the time in your loop and recalculate the TotalAmount on the basis of the new time.

You do not need to use the count variable.

```
        int time = 1;//1 means 1 year

        int num = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter current balance:");
        double Bal = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter required balance:");
        double required = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter interest rate: %");
        double IR = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        double TotalAmount = Bal * IR / 100 * time + Bal;//math to work out interest gained

        Console.WriteLine("Your balance at the end of year 1 is {0:C}", TotalAmount);//this shows the interest gained over 1 year

        //do
        //{
        // Console.WriteLine(Bal);
        // Bal++;
        // } while (Bal < required);

        //I need the code to keep looping until the bal is the same as required
        do
        {
            time++;
            TotalAmount = Bal * IR / 100 * time + Bal;//math to work out interest gained

        } while (TotalAmount < required);
        Console.WriteLine("It took {0} years to get to {1:C}", time, required);
```

Comment: I guess there should be do
            {
                TotalAmount *= (100f+IR)/100;
                count++;

            } while (TotalAmount < required);  Because interest will be depended on total amount

Comment: @Mitklantekutli I think it would be dependent in the case of Compound Interest, not in the case of Simple Interest.